# `:` versus `:=`

Tags: pattern-matching, documentation

I am going through the Fast introduction for programmers tutorial on Mathematica. The [page](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/patterns/) on patterns has the below line:

> x_ (short for x:_) stands for a pattern whose value will be named x

shouldn't it be '(short for x:=_)' which would suggest that pattern matched by `_` will be bound to the variable x?

Comment: No, not a typo; compare the results of `FullForm[x_]` and `FullForm[x : _]`.

Comment: Also, please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other people have already confirmed that it is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:` and `:=` are two different operations in *Mathematica*.  `:`, shorthand for `Pattern`, is used to represent some form, while `:=`, short for `SetDelayed` is used to say "Okay, replace any instance of the left hand side with the right hand side and re-evaluate rhs at every replacement".

In the context of `x_` vs `x:=_`, `x_` is syntactically/manifestly equivalent to `x:_` or `x:Blank[]` (i.e. Represent by `x` any single entity.), whereas `x:=_` represents "At every occurrence of anything of the form `x` replace it with the pattern object `Blank[]`".

```
x := _; x
Clear@x; x : _
```

> _
>
> x_

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. The question makes sense now and can help others too.